# Which walls are flashable?

Tags: league-of-legends

I found this nice map that indicates where players can [Flash](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Flash) across walls.

[image]

Unfortunately, the range for Flash has been reduced, most recently in the [V1.0.0.129](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/V1.0.0.129) patch in November, 2011. Since this image has no timestamp (and shows the old map textures), it's difficult to determine if it's still up-to-date.

So which sections of walls are still Flashable? And which sections are tricky to Flash over?

Comment: Naturally, we'll have to update answers if the range of flash is changed in a subsequent patch.

Comment: There are walls that you can flash over currently that arn't even marked on this map, what would you like for an answer? Someone to edit that Picture? I could do that...

Comment: @Ender yeah an updated picture would be a great solution

Comment: I actually think the arrows are a bit misleading. I'm assuming that if you can flash over one way, you an flash over the other way. Although I'd really love to see if somebody can find a place where you can only flash one-way.

Comment: This is gonna take me at least a day, as Id like to test out some of the ambiguous areas myself. But ill def post an updated pic as an answer in a bit. check back in a few days and see what I come up with :D

Comment: Can we get an update for the new map?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

ALL of the flash arrows on the picture you posted can be accomplished using the current flash, except two:

- The arrow going down into baron pit. To accomplish this you have to flash diagonally.
- The arrow going up from the brush towards mid tower. Again, if you flash diagonally you can also fix this.

After tons of experimentation, here's what I came up with:
[image: possible flash locations]

All the lines I've drawn are what I deem the "difficult" places where you can flash over. There are a lot more obvious places that I haven't put here that I thought were obvious or trivial, including many of the arrows on the picture you posted. There are also definitely some "difficult" lines I haven't drawn - if you find some crazy ones, let me know!

I tried to maximize the distance you travel in each location, unless for some reason it seems stupid that anyone would want to be flashing in that direction. However, I'm sure many of these aren't perfectly optimal. They're also not pixel perfect, but should be mostly accurate. If you can't seem to carry one out, feel free to message me and I will try give you suggestions. Also, if you want to suggest another spot, or just have questions in general, you may message me as well.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Your map looks right.
Like you said you skipped some of the obvious ones. Just think about this when trying to make the flash. After playing a lot, you'll subconsciously know the range of a tower. Flash is half of that range. If you play a lot of Morgana, Karma, Urgot, Vladamir, or Karthus, their attack range is just shorter than flashes range so if you can barely attack over that wall or can't at all, you can't flash it. Those ideas may be too difficult in game, but I thought it would be nice to note.

Comment: That's a good note. Also, if you play alot of shaco, it might help to know that flash range (400) is almost the same as jack-in-the-box range (425), so if you can put a box across the wall, you can almost always flash it.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by, "There are also definitely some "difficult" lines I haven't drawn." Are there known places that you didn't get the chance to indicate on the map? Or do you mean that as a disclaimer: there are probably other places that you haven't found?

Comment: Also, how did you test all these spots? Did you wait out Flash's 250s cooldown? o_O (impressed)

Comment: The "there are some I have left out" was just a disclaimer - I know for a fact this map isn't perfect. In fact, I have some updates planned if there is enough interest.

Comment: I knew some places from memory, so it was easy to test them. For the other places, I played custom games as shaco with full utility masteries and boots of mobility. Since jack-in-the-box range is just a little higher than flash, I used it to test where it WASN'T possible to flash before I used the summoner. It took me a couple hours to finish testing, but it wasn't all that bad (discovering new flash points/directions kept it interesting).

Comment: @EpiChlo: Not true, if you flash into a wall then you get pushed out of it on the closest side (like ward placements), so you can flash many walls that you can't auto attack over. What you say would be true for Ahri's ult though, since that only goes through walls if you can clear the wall entirely.

Comment: Where did you get the clean map image?

Answer (score 1):

I am not going to edit the whole map but I thought I would add in an important wall that is missing.  The existing red arrows in your question are all still flashable spots as far as I know.

I have added an important spot where you can flash near top lane here:

[image]

(The arrow isn't in quite the right orientation - it should be facing diagonal towards the top right)

It's a tough wall to flash but doable.  You need to be sure your champion is right up against the wall before using flash.  I suggest practising in a custom game a few times before trying it in a real game.  I've seen pros miss this one.

Using this spot can be the difference between escaping a gank and dying when playing top lane.